# Tags in list c#

Tags: c#, list, tags

I want to check objects in a List for their tags. And for each tag that matches "clean" an integer needs to be raised. Is this possible? If so, how can I accomplish this?

Thanks in advance!

P.S.: This is what I have now.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;


public class productManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public string ownerName = "";
    public List<Transform> ingredients = new List<Transform>();
    //public int count = (from Object in List<Transform> ingredients where Object.Tags.Contains("clean") select Object).Count<Transform>();

    void Start(){
        ownerName = transform.name;
        name = ownerName + "'s ingredients";
    }

    void Update(){
        int count = (from Object in List<Transform> where Object.Tags.Contains("clean") select Object).Count<Transform>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Totally possible and also quite easy. Would suggest having a search online and seeing what you can come up with and then asking a specific question. You would learn much better that way.

Comment: I already tried that but finding a simple answer isn't that easy on this subject. At least for me :S.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try with Linq:

`int count = (from Object in List<T> where Object.Tags.Contains("clean") select Object).Count<T>()`

It returns to you the number of objects in that list that contains the tag "clean".

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I can't find a way to make it work. Could you help me? I'm getting the: "An implementation of `Where' query expression pattern could not be found." error. Check my edited post for recent script.

Comment: try this:
'int count = (from o in ingredients where o.Tags.Contains("clean") select o).Count<Transform>();'

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
var itemsWithCleanTag = myList.Where(item => item.Tag == "clean");

foreach(var item in itemsWithCleanTag)
{
    item.Raise(5);
}
```